# Javascript conflict with 'this' reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript code (using jQuery) that says:

```
$('.duration').each(function() {
    $(this).html(this.duration_text);
});
```

It's iterating over each element of class 'duration' and setting the text as needed. The problem, is that the text it is setting is from a member variable, hence the this.duration_text. The 'this' reference is getting clobbered by the 'this' reference used by jQuery in the iteration.

How can I avoid this collision?

Although the underlying concept of the answer may be the exact same as the question this is marked as a duplicate of, it isn't immediately clear to me that this is the same question. In hindsight, sure, but while searching myself I didn't find it, nor was it clear it was the same question if I did find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reference to `this` before you create your loop, and then use `self` to refer to your object that has a property `duration_text`:

```
var self = this;
$('.duration').each(function() {
    $(this).html(self.duration_text);
});
```

although you can just do:

```
$('.duration').html(this.duration_text);
```

Comment: Simple and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure variable to hold the reference to the outer object

```
var self = this;
$('.duration').each(function() {
  $(this).html(self.duration_text);
});
```

But in the given snippet since you are assigning the same content to all `duration` elements, you can just use

```
$('.duration').html(this.duration_text);
```